# express download file via ajax

Tags: ajax, node.js, express

I cant just download a file in response to ajax post request.

```
$(function(){
  $('img.download').click(function() {
    var image_path = $(this).attr('class').split(" ")[1]
    $.ajax({url:'/download',type:'POST',data:{image_path:image_path}})
  })    
})
```

Node.js code

```
app.post('/download',function(req,res){
  //var image_path = req.body.image_path
  //var filename = 'new.png'
  res.set({
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename=\"new.png\"'
  })
  //res.set('Content-type', 'image/png')
  //var filestream = fs.createReadStream('public/uploads/new.png')
  //filestream.pipe(res)
  res.download('public/uploads/new.png')
})
```

Comment: i am able to download via res.download(). what error is it giving you ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though you want the image click to trigger a download dialog.  If this is the case, don't use Ajax.  Send the post and let the browser handle the dialog.  Posting as a result of a click can be accomplished by creating a simple form.

```
$("img.download").click(function () {
  var image_path = $(this).attr('class').split(" ")[1];
  var form = $('<form>', {action: '/download', method: 'POST'});
  form.append($('<input>', {name: 'image_path', value: image_path}));
  form.submit();
});
```

(Note that in your sample, `res.set` of the content-disposition is just going to be overridden in `res.download`.  That's essentially all `res.download` does; it sets the content-disposition and then calls `sendfile`.)